Docker Desktop runtime image variables not getting set
i am trying to build a simple docker image based on ubuntu latest 24.04.
I am trying to install powershell on the image by fetching the latest version from the web but the variable dosent seem to be set.
# base image
FROM ubuntu:24.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y 

# install the packages and dependencies along with jq so we can parse JSON
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    wget \
    vim \
    gnupg \
    gnupg2 \
    jq \
    lsb-release \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common



RUN wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb  \
  && dpkg -i libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb \
  && rm libicu70_70.1-2_amd64.deb

# Download the PowerShell package file
RUN latest_version="$(curl -s -X GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/latest' | jq -r '.tag_name')" \
    && PWSH_VERSION1="$(echo $latest_version | tail -c+2)"

RUN some="whatever"
RUN echo $some
RUN echo $PWSH_VERSION1

The variables some and pwsh_version1 do not have any value.
However when i run them locally inside a wsl ubuntu container they run just fine.
I am running the latest version of docker desktop v4.34.3.
the docker image is being built on a windows 11 machine.

This question is similar to: docker ENV vs RUN export. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If a RUN command sets an environment variable, it won't be persisted beyond the current RUN instruction.  You need to use the ENV instruction to set it, but that can't do command substitution.

@DavidMaze - thank you for explaining it clearly :) ... I solved it by chaining the command together.
